# Which one is correct ? ''You are on the point '' or " You are at the point "

Tags: prepositions

What Sentence or use of preposition is correct what should I say

> You are on the point of a good start

Or

> You are at the right point of a good start

Comment: In this particular instance, you want to say "at" instead of "on". But if you saw your brother Billy standing on a bluff overlooking the sea, you'd say "Billy is on the point". And if you were later having an argument with Billy and your friend Sally said something to support you, you'd say "Sally is on point" (i.e. Sally is correct; she made a cogent *point* in the discussion).

Comment: confused . So at my situation of sentence which one is correct ?

Comment: Re-read the first sentence of my comment, please.

Comment: Can you please clarify the idea you are trying to express with this sentence?  They both sound unclear to me, and neither is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

When you are *at* something, that something is typically a *place* - whether:

- a physical area that one travels to
- or a logical idea of "place" referring to "where" one is during some progressive activity like a project or race.

*Point* can be a synonym for *place* in both situations, though *point* would infer a narrower area than a place.

When you are *on* something, you are typically touching it and usually physically above it.  (Of couse, *on* and *at* like many English prepositions have multiple meanings and appear in phrasal verbs.)

So this obivously can be true of many types of physical places.

> I am at First Street. (First Street is a place)
>
> I am on First Street. (You're physically standing on First Street)

Not so much with "logical" places:

> I am at a good stopping point with this project and can take a break.
>
> I am on a good stopping point with this project and can take a break.

To me the second sentence sounds a bit awkward though it's not completely unclear.

*On point* is also a well-known phrase meaning "well prepared" or "excellently done" so the use of *on* and *point* could be potentially confusing.

Answer (score 0):

[countable] a particular time or stage of development
The climber was at/on the point of death when they found him.

From Oald, point, no. 6  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/point_1?q=point